# Print chars back until beginning of the line

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider the file `foo.txt`:

```
some simple text
and another line in the file
```

Read the file with

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()
```

I'd like to print all chars from position `i` to the beginning of the line which contains the char at position `i`.

For example, if `i` is the position of `h` from *another* in the 2nd line, how to discover `j` so that `print data[j,i]` returns `and anoth`?

I tried to search back while char is not `\n` but I think that it could not work if the file has a single line.

So, is there a char representing the beginning of the line? I tried `^` but it does not work.

**MWE**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

with open('foo.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()

for i,c in enumerate(data):
    print i,c

# i = 16 is the 1st \n
# so procedure below does not work if 
# the file contains a single line

i = 25        # position of h.    problem with i = 13 for example.
print data[i] # confirming that

j = i
while data[j] != "\n":
    j -= 1

print data[j:i+1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use `rfind` to find the last newline.

```
data = myfile.read()

i = 25  # position of the h

j = data[:i].rfind("\n")
```

`j` is now the position of the last newline before `data[i]`. Increment that once (so you drop the newline) and you can slice correctly.

```
result = data[j+1:i+1]
```

This has the added benefit of still working if there is no newline, since `rfind` returns `-1` if it finds nothing.

Comment: Very nice. It is what I was looking for.

Comment: Is the last char in `data` another `\n`? Is this a default or maybe my file ends with `\n` because the editor I used to create it?

Comment: The last character in most text files is a newline. I don't think `file.read` puts one there if there isn't one to begin with, though.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just read it line by line?

```
i = 8

with open('foo.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        print line[:i+1]
```

Comment: What I wrote about `h` is just an example. In my case, I don't know what would be the `char`. Inside some tests, I need to print everything back that char.

Comment: @Sigur Then just remove the `if` clause, but this will print up to the i'th character in every line.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can read line by line because I'm applying a function on the whole file to search for non matching parentheses. Let me think. Thanks for a while.